# Make style only apply on URLs that start with a string

Tags: macos, safari, css

In Safari > Advanced > Style sheet I can add my own custom stylesheet to Safari.

How can I write some styles that should only be applied on certain websites, based on the first part of the URL?

Comment: For site-specific restyling, I generally use a Safari extension like Userscripts ( https://github.com/quoid/userscripts ), and then write a userstyle ( https://github.com/openstyles/stylus/wiki/Writing-UserCSS  ) for those specific sites

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with a workaround that is likely to almost always work: Use this selector:

```css
body:has(a[href^="https://site.com/your-url/"]) rest-of-selector {
```

Maybe the `href`s are all local which could make this less useful, e.g. `<a href="/questions/...">` instead of `<a href="https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/...">`, but there may be other uniquely identifying content in your target webpages that you can put into the `:has` selector.

Comment: Any style modifications are susceptible to the site updating its HTML/CSS. But nice hack with `body:has()`, didn't know about this.